# OS X Lion Finder and Open/Save sheets: How to list folders before files?

Tags: macos, file-management, finder, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you sort files in OS X Finder so folders appear at the top?](https://superuser.com/questions/185437/how-do-you-sort-files-in-os-x-finder-so-folders-appear-at-the-top)

I'm a recent Mac convert, but I miss the way Windows and many Unix file browsers list folders before files. It's a personal preference I realize not everyone shares. Listing folders before files just makes things a lot easier for my way of working.

In the Mac Finder, I usually use Column view. But regardless of Column view or not, is there a way to get the Finder (and hopefully other places like Open/Save sheets) to list folders before files?

Comment: There is a good tutorial on how to do this [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/67100/force-your-mac-to-put-folders-on-top-of-files-windows-style/).

Comment: Unfortunately I came across that prior to posting here. The file they expect you to edit, looks nothing like or even has a reference point that is similar to that of which they show.